# Showing Convergence in measure with some condition.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X,M,m)$ be a finite measurable space and $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real valued measurable functions on $X$ . Let $$E_n=\{x\in X : f_n(x)\ne 0\}$$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ .
>   Show that if $ E_n \cap E_m =\emptyset $ for every $n\ne m$ then $f_n\to f $ in measure $m$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D_n = \cup_{k=1}^n E_k$, then $m(D_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n m(E_k)$, $m(D_n)$ is bounded by $m(X)$ and it is increasing, so it is a Cauchy sequence, which means for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ such that for all $n > N$ we have $m(E_n) < \epsilon$.

Now remark that $\{ |f_n -0| \geq \epsilon\} \subset \{f\neq 0\} = E_n$, so $f_n$ converge to $f=0$ in measure